# How to access variables when preparing for segue?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uistoryboardsegue

I'm preparing for a Segue (just learning at the moment!) and want to pass an array, which is created in a function, through a segue to arrive at the new view controller.

It's working fine if I just put a text string in there, but when I try change to an array it is blank - I think because it can't access the array because it's outside the scope - but I'm stuck on how to do it

Here's the initial VC code :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


    if segue.identifier == "goToWorkout" {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? WorkoutViewController {
            destVC.workoutName = (testArray)

    }
    }
     //Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
     //Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

func testfunction() {
    let testArray = ["blah","blah","ploop"]
}
```

and the 'receiving VC code'

```
class WorkoutViewController: UIViewController {


var workoutName = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(workoutName)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I'm nearly there with it but think I must be missing something basic.  How do you do this passing arrays/other variables created in functions?

If the function had more than 1 variable/array, would that change the approach? I.e. one function might produce the exercises in the workout AND the number of reps for example

Answer (score 1):

You can send it in sender

```
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToWorkout ", sender: testArray)
```

and in

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

   if segue.identifier == "goToWorkout" {
       if let destVC = segue.destination as? WorkoutViewController {
          destVC.workoutName = sender as! [String]

   }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to avoid the force unwrapping for the sender (sender as! [String]); Imagine that at some point there is another perform for the same segue but without the need of passing anything. the app would crash.

Comment: @AhmadF You - the developer – are responsible to know if there is *another perform for the same segue* and handle the case. Force unwrapping is not evil per se and optional binding is not a *don't care* alibi.

Comment: @vadian  first sorry bro for the old tensions :) , second yes you are right force unwrap is perfect when you full aware of what you do ,  Ahmed i think it's another use case that the developer may send empty [] or whatever the workaround

Answer (score 0):

```
func testfunction() -> [String] {
    return ["blah","blah","ploop"]
}
```

I guess this is what you want. Functions / methods can return values. It can be achieved by the `->` syntax.

Now you can use like:

```
destVC.workoutName = testfunction()
```

**Few notes**

Functions, methods and variables should be named through camel case notation. So, instead of `testfunction` you should write `testFunction` (maybe choose a better name also).

Do not forget to read Apple documentation on the subject: [Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both occurrences of `testArray` are not in the same scope and the compiler complains.

Declare the function this way

```
func testfunction() -> [String] {
    let testArray = ["blah","blah","ploop"]
    return testArray
}
```

and assign the array by calling the function

```
destVC.workoutName = testfunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by `testArray` being a local variable defined inside the `testfunction` function making it only accessible from inside the function. If you want to make a variable accessible from everywhere inside the class, you'll have to make it an instance property.

```
class InitialVC: UIViewController {
    let testArray = ["blah","blah","ploop"]

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToWorkout" {
            if let destVC = segue.destination as? WorkoutViewController {
                destVC.workoutName = testArray

            }
        }
        //Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        //Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When saying:

```
destVC.workoutName = (testArray)
```

in the `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method, it *definitely* doesn't refers to `testArray` variable in `testfunction()`, since it is a local variable. If you are not getting a compile time error at the above line, then probably your declaring `testArray` somewhere in the view controller or maybe globally in the app.

So what you could do is to declare `testfunction()` as `testfunction() -> [String]`:

```
func testfunction() -> [String] {
    return["blah","blah","ploop"]
}
```

thus:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToWorkout" {
        if let destVC = segue.destination as? WorkoutViewController {
            destVC.workoutName = testfunction()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful - and, if in reality, the function was more complex and produced say 5 arrays, wth one of those being a different type (Int) for example, could you do -> [string], [int] and return various arrays/variables?

Comment: @nc14 well, that depends on what is the logic of passing the arrays, how many array do you have to pass? what are the types of them? because it seems that it would be another story :)